# How to make two different cubits and states in bloc consumer?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have two cubits and states => DeviceBloc, DeviceScreen and StatisticsCubit, StatisticsState.

And I want to use all of them in one page(bloc consumer). How can I do this?

This is my code, I want to add StatisticsCubit, StatisticsState inside BlocCinsumer

```
return BlocConsumer<DeviceScreenBloc, DeviceScreenState>(
        listener: (context, state) async {}
       );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap a `BlocConsumer` in another `BlocConsumer` like so:

```
    BlocConsumer<DeviceScreenBloc, DeviceScreenState>(
      listener: (context, deviceScreenState) {},
      builder: (context, deviceScreenState) {
        return BlocConsumer<StatisticsCubit, StatisticsState>(
          listener: (context, statisticsState) {},
          builder: (context, statisticsState) {
            ...
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just nest the bloc builder method and create the proper implementations.

```
    class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
             appBar: _buildAppbar(context),
             body: BlocConsumer<TasksCubit, TasksStates>(
                listener: (context, state) {},
                builder: (context, state) {
                   return BlocConsumer<TasksOperationsCubit, TasksOperationsStates>(
                     listener: (operationsContext, operationsState) {
                       if (operationsState is InsertIntoDatabaseSuccessState ||
                  operationsState is DeleteTaskItemSuccessState ||
                  operationsState is UpdateTaskItemSuccessState) {
                TasksCubit.get(context).getAllTasks();
              }
            },
            builder: (operationsContext, operationsState) {
                return _buildTasks(state.tasks);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```